# Can I get attachments using ctx discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I know that you can use this code

```
message.attachments[0].url
```

to get the url of the image that the user sent in the on_message event, is it possible to get an attachment using ctx instead or I am I stuck to using on_message if I want to get an image?

Comment: You can get the message with [`ctx.message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.message), so `ctx.message.attachments[0].url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ctx.message.attachments[0].url`